# Como colocar imagens ao lado da outra em colunas?

Tags: html, css, imagem

Quero deixar as imagens uma do lado da outra corratamente com o mesmo tamanho de margens e colunas etc. Como eu faço?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.w3grayscale {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3grayscale">
  <div class="w3-half">
    <img src="recepcao1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="sala1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="sala2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="sala3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="sala4.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="sala1.webp" style="width:100%">

  </div>

  <div class="w3-half">
    <img src="recepcao2.jpg" style="width:00%">
    <img src="sala4.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="sala5.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="sala1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="sala2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="sala3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <!-- End Page Content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Vc reparou que a primeira imagem da segunda div não está aparecendo, e isso está desalinhando a imagem da segundo coluna? É esse o seu problema ai??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo com a mesma quantidade de imagens que você colocou:

```
<style>
    .w3grayscale {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    .allContent{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;

    }
    img{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
        height: 50%;
    }
</style>

<div class="w3grayscale">
    <div class="allContent">
        <div class="w3-half">
            <img src="exemple.png">
            <img src="exemple.png">
            <img src="exemple.png" >
            <img src="exemple.png" >
            <img src="exemple.png" >
            <img src="exemple.png" >

        </div>

        <div class="w3-half">
            <img src="exemple.png" >
            <img src="exemple.png" >
            <img src="exemple.png" >
            <img src="exemple.png" >
            <img src="exemple.png" >
            <img src="exemple.png" >
        </div>
    </div>
  <!-- End Page Content -->
</div>
```

[image: Como ficou:]

Nesse caso, adicionei uma div ao seu HTML, para haver um espaçamento visivelmente agradável, além do uso do justify-content: space-around. As imagens possuem 25% de width para serem encaixadas de acordo com o fluxo.

Answer (score 0):

Caique, tudo bem?
Você pode utilizar o **align-items: flex-end** para dizer que você quer alinhar suas duas "**div w3-half**" no final da "**div w3grayscale**"

Segue o exemplo:

```
.w3grayscale {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}


.w3-half{ width:50%; margin-left: 5px;}
```

Caso ainda tiver dúvidas, por favor me diga para que eu possa lhe ajudar!